# Protractor if else statement with expect

Tags: javascript, automation, jasmine, protractor

I have three codes that i want to check if one of them exists. When i run my code i get a message saying "Expected false to be true". What am i doing wrong

```
var Ecode1 = element(by.xpath('.//*[contains(text(),\'201\')]'));
  var Ecode2 = element(by.xpath('.//*[contains(text(),\'202\')]'));
  var Ecode3 = element(by.xpath('.//*[contains(text(),\'501\')]'));
if (expect(Ecode1.isPresent()).toBe(true)) {
    //ecode1 rules
  } 
  else if (expect(Ecode2.isPresent()).toBe(true)) {
    //ecode2 rules
  }
  else if (expect(Ecode3.isPresent()).toBe(true)) {
   //ecode3 rules
      }
  else {
    browser.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as `isPresent` is promise like the solution would be:

`async/await` approach:

```
if (await Ecode1.isPresent()) {

} else if (await Ecode2.isPresent()) {

} else if (await Ecode3.isPresent()) {

} else {
  browser.close();
}
```

Web Driver `Control Flow` approach is pretty ugly and would require additional complexity:

```
Promise.all([
    Ecode1.isPresent(),
    Ecode2.isPresent(),
    Ecode3.isPresent()
]).then((result)=>{
    // Ecode1 present
    if(result[0]) {

    }
    // Ecode2 present
    else if(result[1]) {

    }
    // Ecode3 present
    else if(result[2]) {

    }
    else {
        browser.close();
    }
});
```

Also, `expect`'s under `if` statements are redundant

Comment: I have a condition under my second if statement. I am basically force failing it. Even though the it should force fail,it skips over a passes it. Any idea?                                                                           
       if (Ecode1.isPresent()) {
        //ecode1 rules
  } 
  else if (Ecode2.isPresent()) {
    throw new Error(msg || 'Test failed');
  }
  else if (Ecode3.isPresent()) {
   //ecode3 rules
      }
  else {
    browser.close();

Comment: @yong -  if edcode1 is not present, it should go to the next block right.

Comment: @yong , i tried this and it still always goes to the first if statement:                                  if (Ecode1.isPresent()) {
    //ecode1 rules
    console.log('CHKPT. 1');
  } 
  else if (Ecode2.isPresent()) {
    console.log('CHKPT. 2');
    throw new Error(msg || 'Test failed');
  }
  else if (Ecode3.isPresent()) {
   //ecode3 rules
   console.log('CHKPT. 3');
      }
  else {
    console.log('CHKPT. 4');
    browser.close();
    
  }

Comment: @automationG what approach do you have? `async/await` or webdriver `control flow`?

Comment: Thanks.  "ispresent" is a boolean i guess that was the issue. Your solution worked.